# Are ViewBags appropriate for passing scalar values to the View from Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I first learned MVC 5 (a few months ago), I saw frequently in the tutorials  "People use ViewBags to fill dropdownlists in forms. You shouldn't use ViewBag, but for this example, we'll use it (that is -- we'll do the thing that we shouldn't do, rather than show you what you should be doing)."

The correct action, I have been told, is to create a ViewModel. When you are doing (using database language) a table join, or transforming properties in the data model so they appear as desired in the ViewModel, this makes perfect sense.

However, what if you are trying to pass scalar data one-way from the Controller to the View? If those scalar values are dependent on values passed into the Controller Action parameters and are not tabular in fashion, is a ViewBag such a bad thing?

I have pasted a concept showing where I am getting at. So if my ViewModel should contain (what is in my mind) two distinct categories of information that take two different forms, then what is the appropriate way to communicate those scalar value if not a ViewBag?

[image: concept of data model paired with scalar values]

I even tried this in my ViewModel, but it did not work as intended for reasons that I think make sense because of the posted image. I need "SelectedCampus" to be passed to the View so that other clickable links and jQuery can use it as a parameter value, but I *don't* intend for it to be tabular. I only intend for the tabular data to show in the table on the View.

A common response is, "Why not just add that property to your ViewModel?" Here is my mental block: the data model is a table, which might contain hundreds of records.

A scalar value is a single value. If I add a scalar value to a table (i.e., what amounts as a constant value in the table), I'm replicating that scalar value by the number of records. Each scalar value I add adds that much more duplicate information to the table. Now add IEnumerables (i.e., lists which might have more than one column, or not).

If this were a relational database, my first instinct would be to take out any duplication because the table is no longer normalized. I know, C# is object oriented and is not relational, but hopefully the mental block I have becomes apparent when I question the wisdom of replicating scalar values in a table.

Furthermore, the scalar values are not to be shown in the Table of the View, but rather to populate dropdownlists in the Html.BeginForm block and to supply parameter values for ActionLinks and jQuery functions.  Hopefully this helps to clarify what I am trying to ask.

```
// ViewModel
public class StudentRosterViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Campus { get; set; }

    public string FiscalYear { get; set; }

    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    public string SelectedCampus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you asking - what is `string Campus` vs `string SelectedCampus`? (are you meaning a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property for use in a dropdownlist?

Comment: That describes part of the issue. I need to have a dropdown of all possible campuses -- that's the role of the IEnumerable<SelectListItem>. But I also need that value of the that selected campus that's posted to the Controller Action so that jQuery code and other clickable functions can use that value.

Comment: This seems opinionated, but I avoid `ViewBag` like the plague. The use of objects are more OOP and lead to less confusion.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge, So therefore your view model would contain a property `string Campus` (or `SelectedCampus`) to bind the selected option to, and a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CampusList` for displaying the options in the dropdownlist.

Comment: I have done that approach, and the IEnumerable was not available in the View unless I did a nested foreach loop.  Html.Dropdownlist wouldn't even touch it.. Lacking a complete tutorial on this subject, this is what led me to raise the question. I've spent two days mucking about trying to get a simple hello world ViewModel as I describe to work -- without success.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge, Not sure what you mean _the IEnumerable was not available in the View_. Its simply a matter of initializing your view model in the GET method and assigning ts property - e.g. `model.CampusList = new SelectList(db.Campus, "ID", "Name");` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Campus, Model.CampusList)`

Comment: Herein lies the problem of being encouraged by convention of keeping it simple but not presenting the whole backstory in the question. I'll mark the overall question as being answered and walk away for a few days. All because I have yet to see a complete tutorial on this topic, which is another story altogether.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge - the disconnect here is that your model need not be tabular, and may contain tabular data.  ie, you have a model that contains single elements, like your SelectedCampus, and then your model also contains a property like Students that have your tabular student data.

Comment: I attempted that, if you're thinking of a ViewModel by Composition. While I could loop through the ViewModel by Debug.WriteLine in the Controller, I was unable to then create the "VIew" of that Action. This is where I really wish there were a basic -- complete -- tutorial on this topic rather than the fragmented ones I see. Maybe my issues really are trivial, but getting it to work is the problem. I've even purchased hardcover books, but I still see the "You shouldn't use ViewBags, but we'll use them in this example."  Banging face on desk now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewBag` is better for simple elements like the page title which aren't really specific to one view, and they're usually in our layout view. Other than that, view models are preferable. It's easier to follow where the data comes from using strongly-typed models. Nearly anything in our view can be traced to the model, and then we can inspect the properties of the model to see where they are set.

That's lost if our views contain references to `@ViewBag.Xyz`. It's a bit like throwing away strongly-typed models and replacing them with a `Dictionary<string, object>`. There's nothing to clearly indicate what any given value should contain, or if it even needs to exist. View models cause the compiler to enforce integrity between the model and the view (and indirectly between the model and the controller.) That goes out the window with `ViewBag`.

I'm not saying I'd be fanatic about it. There are often exceptions and reasons for doing things. But if someone cuts the corner of placing data in the view model and sticks it in `ViewBag` instead I'd wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing right or wrong about either approach. View bags are very useful for small bits of data, but view models have the big advantage of being strongly typed, which removes a big source of potential bugs.

I almost never use view bag properties, mainly for the strongly typed reason, but it's certainly an acceptable way of doing it.

If you end up with more than a couple of view bag properties, then it sounds like you should be using a view model.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it's getting tabular data and scalar data -- and possibly IEnumerables -- into the same ViewModel. That's where i am having a mental block.

Comment: @Rubix what exactly is your problem with it? Just create a class that has a public property for each bit of data you want in the view, then set the class type as your view's model. Should all work fine. Can't post any code now as I'm on a tablet, but if you explain where you're having your mental block, I'll try and post some code tomorrow.

Comment: Part of it is a paradigm issue on my part. Bear with me for a moment. Imagine a data entity (i.e., a table) that might have a few hundred rows. Then you want to pass a single value. If you add it to the viewmodel, you're passing it once times the number of records in your query. So one scalar value gets multiplied by the number of rows. Now consider doing an extra column in your ViewModel for each scalar value. Now add an Ienumerable. All I want to do is pass on scalar units that are independent of the data model, but it seems like I'm over-duplicating information by adding scalars to a table.

Comment: The other unrelated problem I experienced was getting my ViewModel properties to appear on the View -- apparently they were in the ViewModel definition, but were not IEnumerable. More gaps not shown in the ViewModel samples. I need to take a break from this, but I'll append my question with some more code to perhaps add clarity.